# Pre-creating objects in a separate thread

Tags: java, concurrency

Suppose I have a Java method like:

```
public Ouput respond(Input input) { /* .. */ }
```

The `Output` object has many fields - some of those fields depend on the `Input` object but the rest are pre-determined. I want to make the thread which calls `respond()` to return as fast as possible.

For this I want to spawn another thread which pre-creates `Output` object, sets some of the fields and puts them in a queue so that the thread running `respond()` can pick it up from the queue, set the remaining fields and return it.

What is the best way to implement something like this? My current prototype uses a bounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` but are there better ways to implement this idea?

My aim is to get the `respond()` method as fast as possible, so other suggestions which meet that goal are also welcome. :-)

Comment: In order to help you optimize the method, we'd have to see the code for the `Output` class; it's important to know what the fields we're talking about are.  (I say this because it seems that constructing an instance of `Output` with default values for a bunch of its fields isn't that time-intensive a process...)

Comment: @delfuego I made up code above; the actual code is more complicated but my tests/profiling indicate that the object construction overhead is significant. The `Output` class is in a 3rd party lib who source I don't have access to.

Comment: Why Linked and not Array? I would (perhaps naively) assume that the ArrayBlockingQueue performs slightly better than the LinkedBlockingQueue just because the array implementation doesn't have the additional overhead of maintaining the link objects.

Comment: @Suppressingfire Good point! Since the queue is bounded, an implementation backed by arrays sound better.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a case where you could make good use of `Future`s and `Executor`s. See more here:

- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html
- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Here's a concrete example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

final Input input = ...
Future<Output> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Output>() {
  public Output call() {
    return respond(input);
  }
});

// do some work

Output output = future.get();  // this blocks until it's done
```

In your case, since you mentioned that some of the fields in the `Output` object are to be used immediately, while others are used at a later point, you could structure your `Output` object to contain futures as fields. For example:

```
public class Output {
   private String fieldA; // immediate field
   private Future<String> fieldB; // delayed field

   public void setFieldA(String fieldA) { this.fieldA = fieldA; }
   public String getFieldA() { return fieldA; } 
   public void setFieldB(Future<String> fieldB) { this.fieldB = fieldB; }
   public Future<String> getFieldB() { return fieldB; }
}
```

You'd then structure your respond method like this:

```
public Output respond(final Input input) {
   Output output = new Output();
   String fieldA = ...
   output.setFieldA(fieldA);

   Future<String> fieldBFuture = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
     public String call() {
       String fieldB = ...
       return fieldB;
     }
   }

   output.setFieldB(fieldBFuture);
}
```

And to use your `Output` object:

```
Input input = ...
Output output = respond(input);

String fieldA = output.getFieldA();
// do some work
String fieldB = output.getFieldB().get();
```

Comment: @toluju I did not understand how `Executor`s can be useful in this context - can you please outline the algorithm?

Comment: @binil Added example for you, let me know if that clears things up.

Comment: toluju, binil mentioned above that `Output` is provided by a 3rd-party library to which he has no source access; it looks like this method would require him to be able to modify the class, which he can't do.

Comment: Right, I forgot that part. You could still wrap the original `Output` class to accomplish the same task though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can adapt your implementation that Output-objects do not have to be created for every respond()-call but to recycle Output-objects when they are not needed anymore. Resetting fields should be faster than creating them from scratch and if you have a high object-throughput it also saves you some time in the garbage-collection and you can also improve cache-performance of the processor and Java VM.

Of course this can only work if you can control the whole process and can change the caller who gets the result of respond().

But if you really have such high performance-requirements this could be another idea to play around with. Just don't make it too complicated to be maintainable anymore.

Comment: @Kosi2801 Unfortunately, I have no control over the lifecycle of the created object so object-pooling might not be easy to implement in my case. Nonetheless, it is something I should think about - thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 2):

Unless creating the object used by fields of Output are fairly expensive, the cost of using another thread will be many times greater than the cost of setting a few fields.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an object-creation factory that, on construction, pre-populates an internal store of `Output` objects, doles them out on request, and contains logic to know when it's necessary to repopulate the internal store?  Perhaps something like this (note that this is just off-the-top-of-my-head simplecode; there are clear places where you can do a lot more, like have specific algorithms to determine when the pool has too few objects, synchronize on repopulation, etc.):

```
public class OutputFactory {

    private List<Output> outputPool = new LinkedList<Output>();

    public OutputFactory() {
        this.populatePool();
    }

    private void populatePool() {
        // spawn a new thread here, if you wish, to optimize time-to-return
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            outputPool.add(new Output());
        }
    }

    public Output getNewOutput() {
        Output newOutput = outputPool.remove(0);
        if (outputPool.size() < 10) {
            populatePool();
        }
        return newOutput;
    }

}
```

Comment: This would block every 100th request when the pool has to be refilled and that's not the intended behaviour. I guess that's the reason why the Asker refers to another thread for the Output-generation, so that every request() returns as fast as possible and not only 99 out of 100.

Comment: Kosi2801, that's why I said that you could spawn a new thread there if you wanted to and return immediately; I just wrote it out as pseudo/simplecode to convey the entire idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since all threads are sharing the same heap, I can't imagine that creating them on a different thread is going to make much of a difference as far as allocation is concerned. If you are seeing a benefit from threading, it would be due to whatever computation is required to set the pre-determined fields on the Output object.

If that's the case, you might do even better to have a single template Output object with the predetermined fields pre-filled, and then simply have `respond()` clone the shared template object. (If the object is not already Cloneable and you can't make it so, it would cost about the same to copy the fields yourself.)

If the template thing doesn't work, but you could recycle Output instances, that's probably an even better option, as no new memory needs to be allocated at all, and the predetermined fields don't even need to be copied; they will already be set.

Either of those strategies would allow you to speed up the `respond()` method without the overhead of a separate thread.

Comment: @benzado You are right that allocation is going to take the same amount of time, irrespective of which thread I do it on. I am trying to improve the perceived performance of the respond() method by doing the allocation earlier. Think of it like a fast-food restaurant - the food takes the same amount of time to cook regardless of when you cook it, but the customers perceive faster service if you have the food cooked ahead-of-time.

Comment: It's not "perceived" performance, it's latency that you're trying to improve. Anyway, both the methods I suggested should help in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the fields are truly "pre-determined" why not make them static on the Output class?

Comment: By "pre-determined" I meant that they don't depend on `Input`, but can be determined even before anyone calls `respond()`.

Comment: Do they differ between respond() calls?